# How to dynamically changed ContentPage Title inside XAML in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a variable `var wordsCount = App.words.Count.ToString();` inside my OnAppearing() method in C#. How can I pass the value of the wordsCount to the title property of the contentpage in the XAML side so everytime I go to that page the title is updated accordingly? Kind of like the below code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
        x:Class="Japanese.PhrasesPage"
        Title="wordsCount">
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the code behind of your page override `OnAppearing()` and set the `Title` property:

```
override void OnAppearing()
{
  Title = wordsCount;
}
```

If you would like to use bindings, you need to set the `BindingContext` and make your field a public property:

```
public class MyPage : ContentPage
{
  public ContentPage()
  {
    BindingContext = this;
  }

  public string WordCount { get { return wordCount; }}
}
```

And in XAML:

`Title="{Binding WordCount}"`